# How do I show that this function is continuous?

Tags: general-topology, continuity, homotopy-theory, quotient-spaces

I'm interested in showing that $CX=\frac{I\times X}{\{1\}\times X}$ is contractible.

I defined the d.r $F(s,[t,x])=[(1-s)t+s,x]$ and the only missing part for me is to show that it is continuous.
How do I do that?

I did see some related questions (example: [J. J. Rotman's proof that the cone is contractible](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/774130/j-j-rotmans-proof-that-the-cone-is-contractible/774182#comment2585938_774182) ), but couldn't understand completly why $F$ is continuous iff $F\circ(q×1)$ is continuous.

Also, is there a more traditional way to show the continuity?

Thanks

Comment: oh stop that, like I didn't see this question. I asked because I didn't understand it there, as i did mention in this thread. I'm allowed to ask for clarifications. plus i asked for a traditional way as well.

Comment: You need the result that a.r. cites at the end. It's not that easy, but, as a.r. writes in the beginning, that's just how it is.